# How do I manipulate Data from one column of a csv file using Unix Script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a csv that has data looking something like this,

```
123,Jeff,NY

456,Ross,LA

789,John,OH
```

I have to write a script that manipulates only first column and change the numbers to desired characters like show below,

```
ABC,Jeff,NY

DEF,Ross,LA

GHI,John,OH
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change numbers from 1 to 9 by letters A to I, use `tr` command:

```
tr 1-9 A-I <file
```

Since only the first column of your input file contains numbers, only that column will be changed.

Comment: You can restrict the transformation to the first column with something like `awk '{printf "%s,", $1 | c; close c; print $2, $3}' c="tr 1-9 A-K" OFS=, FS=, input`

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F, -ane '$,=","; $F[0] =~ s/([0-9])/chr(ord("A") + $1)/eg; print @F' input
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple bash solution

```
#!/bin/bash


F="$1"
[ -z "$F" ] && {
        echo "Usage: $0 csv-file"
        exit 1
}

chars=( {A..Z} )
while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo "${chars[($(echo $line | cut -b1)-1)]}${chars[($(echo $line | cut -b2)-1)]}${chars[($(echo $line | cut -b3)-1)]},"$(echo $line | cut -f2- -d,)
done < "$F"
```

**Explanation:**

Get the file as first parameter, exit if none is given

```
F="$1"
[ -z "$F" ] && {
        echo "Usage: $0 csv-file"
        exit 1
}
```

Declare the alphabet array

```
chars=( {A..Z} )
```

Loop the file and for each line use the 3 digits from the csv to get the alphabet array index

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo "${chars[($(echo $line | cut -b1)-1)]}${chars[($(echo $line | cut -b2)-1)]}${chars[($(echo $line | cut -b3)-1)]},"$(echo $line | cut -f2- -d,)
done < "$F"
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are **numbers on other columns** and you want to replace only on the **first column,** you can try to create a new transformed column (by extracting and replacing using **tr and cut** commands, and then joining with **paste** commands) :

```
paste -d',' <(cat abc.txt | cut -d"," -f1 | tr 1-9 A-I) abc.txt

ABC,123,Jeff,NY
,
DEF,456,Ross,LA
,
GHI,789,John,OH
```

Now you can the **remove the blank lines** that have a leading comma

```
paste -d',' <(cat abc.txt | cut -d"," -f1 | tr 1-9 A-I) abc.txt|grep -v "^,"

ABC,123,Jeff,NY
DEF,456,Ross,LA
GHI,789,John,OH
```

Finally, you can **select only the columns** you need using the **cut** command :

```
paste -d',' <(cat abc.txt | cut -d"," -f1 | tr 1-9 A-I) abc.txt|grep -v "^,"| cut -d"," -f2,3,4

123,Jeff,NY
456,Ross,LA
789,John,OH
```

Comment: In the last command you want the transformed column 1, not 2: `-f1,3-`.

Comment: In the first command you can cut on the remaining fields: `paste -d',' <(cat abc.txt | cut -d"," -f1 | tr 1-9 A-I) <(cut -d"," -f2- <abc.txt)`